# Unity ARSessionOrigin

Tags: unityscript

I am working with unity AR but i am having a problem while inserting ARSessionOrigin. if i use ARSessionOrigin Showing warning like

```
Assets\Scripts\PlantPlacementManager.cs(11,12): warning CS0618: 'ARSessionOrigin' is obsolete: 'ARSessionOrigin has been deprecated. Use XROrigin instead.*
```

Not accepting the XROrigin
if i use XROrigin in my code then showing error Like
*

```
Assets\Scripts\PlantPlacementManager.cs(11,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'XROrigin' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

[image]

Tell me how to fix this